# Is it safe to use Looper.getMainLooper() in WorkManager?

Tags: android, handler, android-workmanager, android-handler, android-looper

This is how I used WorkManager. As you can see, I use Handler in Worker class. Handler is now deprecated since Android 11. Now we should use Handler(Looper) and I know very little about Loopers. I wonder if it's safe to use `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` in Worker class, what exactly is Looper, and what types of Looper exist other then main Looper.

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {
       new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
            //Do Something
            }});
       return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `Handler`? `doWork()` is called on a background thread, and you are not supposed to return a result until the work is complete.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's a good question. Idk, that's how I learned. Probably bad practice, but it works. Okay, so the code is called in background thread. Should I still use main Looper?

Comment: @RastkoStamenkovic You should remove the handler, it makes no sense in this code. doWork already runs in a background thread, and what you are doing is to post a runnable in the queue of the same background thread. In fact this code may lead to problems, since the thread could be killed before the runnable completes as it is posted into a queue.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I will delete it now and it's good that you corrected me. Thanks for pointing out my mistake @CommonsWare and @PerracoLabs.  I still wonder, out of curiosity, when I have a handler on background thread, should I use `Looper.getMainLooper()` or something else.

Comment: @RastkoStamenkovic When you are in a background thread, if you need to post something into the "main" thread, then yes you instantiate a Handler passing Looper.getMainLooper(), which as said will post a given runnable into the main thread queue for the next execution. What you need to have clear is that whatever you post in a Handler with a different looper, in this case the main looper, will not run at all in the executing background thread. Although if you need to post information from a WorkManager task into the main thread, then you may want to have a look at LiveData instead.

Comment: "when I have a handler on background thread" -- you need to know **why** you have a `Handler`. What is the objective? If the objective is "I need to do this bit of work on the main application thread", then you would need `getMainLooper()` (though you really should be considering RxJava or Kotlin coroutines).

Comment: Excellent, I understand Loopers better now. I've got much to learn, I will dive into RxJava and LiveData. You were super helpful, thanks for your comments.